# Как обновлять JSON на github через хостинг Heroku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, github, heroku

я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что хостинг Heroku не обновляет json файл, который находится на платформе GitHub, но если же если запускать этот же код на у себя на компьютере, то всё обновляется. Как можно исправить данную проблему, чтобы Heroku мог обновлять json файл на github?